# iMacros - remove last character in string

Tags: javascript, java, string, split, imacros

I have a string like "673.35." defined as VAR3.

I simply want to remove the last "." so I am left with "673.35". It is proving very tricky for me. Using free version of iMacros plug-in on Google Chrome.

I cannot use split function or replace function I don't think as there there will always be a decimal point in my string.

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var s = '{{!VAR3}}'; var x,y,z; y = s.split('.'); z = y[1].split('.'); z[0];")
```

This is what I have tried but obviously it returns "35" as I have two decimal points in my string.

Answer (score 1):

For solving such problems the "regular expressions" were invented. I do not know if imacros can handle regular expressions, but since you added "java" as tag I provide here the solution how it would be written in java:

```
    String s = "673.35.";
    String regexp = "^(.*)(\\.?)$";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regexp).matcher(s);

    if ( m.matches() )
    {
        String result = m.group( 1);
        System.out.println( "result: " + result );
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println( "no match");
    }
```

This regexp works for

```
673.53. > 673.53
673.53  > 673.53
12345.  > 12345
12345   > 12345
```

Regexp's seem to be very cryptic, but they are very powerful. Learn about it in the java doc of java.util.regex.Pattern. Here some explanations on above regexp: '^' is "start of line/string", '.*' is "any character(s), '\\.' is "one dot" (since '.' is "any character", the dot itself must be escaped by '\', used in a java string constant the '\' must also be escaped, therefore two '\'), '?' is "once or none" (of preceding definition, here the dot) '$' is "end of line/string". The parantheses group the search result in order to access it afterwards ("m.group(1)").

Comment: You get a '+1' from me, even if Qt has nothing to do with 'Java', iMacros doesn't support 'Java' => but 'JavaScript' (in 'EVAL()')... - I started to edit the Qt to remove the {java} Tag (and add the {javascript} one) and then re-added it when I noticed your Answer... 'REGEXP' can/could also be used with 'JS' similarly to your Answer, but I always find it pretty "cumbersome en complex", there would be "easier" Solutions, still using 'split()', and/or other JS Methods... (The original 'EVAL()' Statement from OP is from me, taken from the iMacros Forum, ah-ah...!)